# How to model an integer-valued (medical) score as response variable in regression

Tags: regression, modeling, ordinal-data

Here is the distribution of my response variable that I have to regress:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 11 15 
2  9  3  7  7  7  6  5  7  1
```

Its a medical score that can take integer values from 0 to 24. The question is: what tool to use?

I have the following options in my mind:

- Linear regression. The response is not continuous, and this scale doesn't seem to be fine enough to disregard this fact.
- Poisson (/quasi-Poisson/NB) regression. The distribution is not Poisson, and it is not supposed to be Poisson, as this is not count data, so this seems to be completely wrong.
- Logistic regression. Multinomial logistic regression is out of question with such low sample size, so proportional odds (ordinal) model seems to be the only possible option. This seems to be fine from 1 to 8, but I'm worried about 8-11-15, as the proportional odds model would consider these to be equal steps.
- Beta regression. Divide the values with 24 (the maximum that is exogenously known) and then regress them as proportions. Seems to be quite indirect solution...
- Binomial regression (with the denominator set to 24). I don't know how well the binomial distribution fits the data, beta distribution certainly looks more flexible, but at least I can use the original data, without transforming them.
- Beta-binomial regression. Just like binomial regression it requires no transformation of the data, but its functional form is more flexible (at the expense of an additional parameter to be estimated).

So I'm stuck here. What is the best approach/what are the pros and cons of these approaches...? Or something else is the solution?

Comment: It seems like you're set on using a discrete-valued response distribution rather than a continuous approximation. Assuming that's the approach you want to use, then the two options you've listed (Binomial and Poisson/related) might be fairly limiting. The binomial only has one parameter (n is set to 24) and the Poisson assumes infinite support. Have you considered a Beta-Binomial response to increase the number of parameters while fixing the support on {0, ..., 24}?

Comment: @jjet "Assuming that's the approach you want to use" Well, that's part of the question (that's why I've listed linear regression), but yes, my impression is that these data are not fine enough to be considered continuous. "Have you considered a Beta-Binomial response to increase the number of parameters while fixing the support on {0, ..., 24}?" Good idea, thank you, I've added it to the list of options (hope I've correctly identified the pros and cons of this approach).

Comment: I tend to use the continuous approximation pretty judiciously. Without seeing the data, it's hard to say if it's fair to apply. But as long as you're creative, you can always make up you're own discretized version of any continuous distribution. The Beta distribution - which you listed - is a flexible but continuous model. You could discretize it but the resulting PMF may not have an analytic form. The Kumaraswamy distribution is similar to the Beta but its CDF is known so it would be much easier to discretize. That would be the only other option I'd look into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a case for ordinal regression such as the proportional odds ordinal logistic model, a generalization of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney-Kruskal-Wallis test.  Much has been written about this model on this site.  The P.O. model does not assume equal steps.  It is completely nonparametric regarding the distribution of Y for a given single value of X.

Comment: Thank you! My problem with the PO model is specifically the "does not assume equal steps" part. You're right that the wording of my question wasn't correct; what I meant is the following: Wouldn't it be more feasible to use a model that understands that the difference between having a score of 11 and 15 is _larger_ than the difference between 7 and 8...? I might even say that it is 4 times larger; this information is discarded by the PO model (if my understanding is correct).

Comment: Ordinal regression models do not use the spacing between any two levels but they do use  the ordering of levels.  So you're right, a long gap between two distinct values is not treated differently than a short gap between two other distinct values.  A major advantage of ordinal semiparametric regression is that if you increasing-monotonically transform $Y$ the regression coefficients and standard errors are unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! And what would be the correct model to take that aspect into account as well...?

Comment: You would have to lose the nonparametric nature and robustness of an ordinal model ad go fully parametric to do that, which will in all likelihood give you a worse model fit.